# How to SHOW/TOAST the related item of the string array on spinner selected from xml parsing

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

How to **Toast** the related value to the string value selected FROM THE SPINNER.

[image]

I am able to get the **spinner data** **from the below xml format**  but not able to pass its **id** to them for toast.

**

```
APIGetCitiesResponse xmlns="http://xxxx">
<APIGetCitiesResult xmlns:a="http://xxxx.xxx" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2010/XMLSchema-instance">
<a:Pair>
<a:FromID>10</a:FromID>      <---This should Toast---->
<a:FromName>INDIA</a:FromName><---On selecting this from spinner ------->
<a:ToID>30</a:ToID>
<a:ToName>TURKEY</a:ToName>
</a:Pair>
<a:Pair>
<a:FromID>40</a:FromID>
<a:FromName>USA</a:FromName>
<a:ToID>10</a:ToID>
<a:ToName>INDIA</a:ToName>
</a:Pair>
<a:Pair>
<a:FromID>19</a:FromID>
<a:FromName>CHINA</a:FromName>
<a:ToID>40</a:ToID>
<a:ToName>USA</a:ToName>
</a:Pair>
<a:Pair>
<a:FromID>30</a:FromID>
<a:FromName>TURKEY</a:FromName>
<a:ToID>10</a:ToID>
<a:ToName>INDIA</a:ToName>
</a:Pair>
</Result>
</Response>
```

**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener {

    ArrayList<String> title;
    ArrayList<String> title2;
    Button button;
    Spinner spinner;
    Spinner spinner2;
    private EditText fromDateEtxt;
    //private EditText toDateEtxt;

    private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    //private DatePickerDialog toDatePickerDialog;

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;

    ArrayAdapter<String> from_adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<String> from_adapter2;
    Map<String, List<String>> values = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        title = new ArrayList<String>();
        title2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        //spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
        findViewsById();

        setDateTimeField();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                parse();

                from_adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title);
                from_adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                title2.clear();
                from_adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, title2);
                from_adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


                spinner.setAdapter(from_adapter);
                //from_adapter2.clear();
                //from_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                spinner2.setAdapter(from_adapter2);


            }

            private Object from_adapter(int i) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

        });


    }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        String lang_Name = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
        List<String> lang_Key = values.get(lang_Name);
        from_adapter2.clear();
            for(String s : lang_Key){
                  from_adapter2.insert(s, from_adapter2.getCount());
            }
            from_adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), ""+lang_Key,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
    }

    protected void parse() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        try {

            URL url = new URL(
                    "www.example.com");
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:Pair");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
                // get the a:W value
                String awValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:FromName").item(0).getTextContent();
                // add the above value in our map  as key if it isn't present in the map, this key will 
                // have a list associated with it in which ALL the values for a:R will be stored, if 
                // the awValue key is present then you just add the new a:R value to its list 
                if (!values.containsKey(awValue)) {
                    values.put(awValue, new ArrayList<String>());

                }
                // also add the value pointed by a:R to the list associated with a:W
                String arValue = el.getElementsByTagName("a:ToName").item(0).getTextContent();
                values.get(awValue).add(arValue);

               // Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " + arValue);
            }
             Log.d("ADebugTag", "Value: " +  values);
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);       

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:FromName");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();         

                NodeList websiteList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:ToName");
                Element websiteElement = (Element) websiteList.item(0);
                websiteList = websiteElement.getChildNodes();

                title.add(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            }
            NodeList nodeList2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:Pair");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList2.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList2.item(i);       

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("a:ToName");
                Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();         
                title2.add(((Node) nameList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            }
            Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(title);
            title = new ArrayList<String>(set);
            // Collection<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>(months);
            Set<String> set2 = new LinkedHashSet<String>(title2);
            title2 = new ArrayList<String>(set2);
            System.out.println("list are");
            System.out.println(set);
            System.out.println("list 2 are");
            System.out.println(set2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view == fromDateEtxt) {
            fromDatePickerDialog.show();
        } else  {
            Log.d("errorrrr", "soryy");
        }

    }
}
```

***Update :1***

**On making changes to  the above code like below,I am getting all the ids if the first spinner in Logcat Log.d("fromid fromid", "fromid: " +  fromid); but how to attach this to the spinner so that if pasticular value is clicked the its particular id is Toasted.**

```
 NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Pair");
    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i);

        String awValue = el.getElementsByTagName("FromName").item(0).getTextContent();
        if (!values.containsKey(awValue)) {
            values.put(awValue, new ArrayList<String>());
            String fromid = el.getElementsByTagName("FromID").item(0).getTextContent();
            Log.d("fromid fromid", "fromid: " +  fromid);

        }
        String arValue = el.getElementsByTagName("ToName").item(0).getTextContent();
        values.get(awValue).add(arValue);
    }
```

Comment: For that you need to get the IDs from the xml just like `title` and `title2`.

Comment: @KNeerajLal please see my UPDATE:1

Comment: @KNeerajLal From xml data like <a:FromID>10</a:FromID> , and from this line of code( String fromid = el.getElementsByTagName("FromID").item(0).getTextContent();) i am getting all the ids in logcat ......should i make arraylist for the ids also .....and then how will i append that to the first spinner data to be toast when clicked

Comment: I mailed you my project  at catchneeraj@hotmail.com,please see to it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109981/discussion-between-k-neeraj-lal-and-android-putra).

Comment: @KNeerajLal please see to the chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109981/discussion-between-k-neeraj-lal-and-android-putra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a POJO class for the xml response cities.

**City.java**

```
public class City {
    int  id;
    String name;

    public City() {
    }

    public City(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    //getters ad setters
}
```

Rather than parsing the xml each time, parse it all in a single loop.

**`parse` method**

```
Map<Integer, City> to = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, City> from = new HashMap<>();

protected void parse() {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kushagrakhare/g/master/test.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("a:CityPair");
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Element el = (Element) nodeList.item(i);
            // get the a:W value
            String fromCityName = el.getElementsByTagName("a:FromCityName").item(0).getTextContent();
            int fromCityID = Integer.parseInt(el.getElementsByTagName("a:FromCityID").item(0).getTextContent());
            int toCityID = Integer.parseInt(el.getElementsByTagName("a:ToCityID").item(0).getTextContent());
            String toCityName = el.getElementsByTagName("a:ToCityName").item(0).getTextContent();

            City from1 = new City(fromCityID, fromCityName);
            City to1 = new City(toCityID, toCityName);
            from.put(fromCityID, from1);
            to.put(toCityID, to1);
        }

        for (City item : from.values()) {
            title.add(item.getName());
        }

        for (City item : to.values()) {
            title2.add(item.getName());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

}
```

Store the selection of each spinner and whenever it changes display the toast.

**`onItemSelected` code**

```
int spinner1SelectionPos;
int spinner2SelectionPos;
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()) {
        case R.id.spinner1:
            spinner1SelectionPos = pos;
            break;
        case R.id.spinner2:
            spinner2SelectionPos = pos;
            break;
    }

    int fcityKey = getMapKey(from, title.get(spinner1SelectionPos));
    int tcityKey = getMapKey(to, title2.get(spinner2SelectionPos));

    String message = title.get(spinner1SelectionPos) + " " + fcityKey
            + " " + title2.get(spinner2SelectionPos) + " " + tcityKey;

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

//for getting key from a map using value
private int getMapKey(Map<Integer, City> map, String value) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, City> item : map.entrySet()) {
        if (item.getValue().getName().equals(value)) return item.getKey();
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal I thing you are driving me to correct path....and is there any possibility to do it in same MainActivity.java class without creating the POJO class ..........could you please give me your mail id ?

Comment: @K Neeraj Lal yaa i have also made pojo class mailed you full project